# Can Doxygen be configured to omit fundamental C++ types from collaboration diagrams?

Tags: c++, documentation, doxygen

Is there a way to prevent Doxygen from including fundamental C++ types (`int`, `float`, etc) in the diagrams it produces?  For example, when a collaboration diagram includes a large number of user-defined types, knowing that they all use `int` internally isn't as useful as seeing the relationships between the types, and the large number of lines from all parts of the diagram to the `int` type makes the diagram visually "busy" and harder to read.

Ideally, code would be sufficiently well-designed and modular that collaboration diagrams would be small and simple, and the inclusion of fundamental types wouldn't be a problem.  But one situation in which Doxygen really shines is when there's a large amount of badly-written code which the user has to get to grips with and get to work on as quickly as possible, and it would be good to simplify the collaboration diagrams in this case.

I know that reducing `MAX_DOT_GRAPH_DEPTH` can simplify collaboration diagrams, but this reduces the number of both user-defined types and fundamental types.  To make the best use of the space available in the diagram, I'd like to include just user-defined types.

Answer (score 1):

With `HIDE_UNDOC_RELATIONS` set to `YES` in the configuration file, doxygen should omit fundamental and otherwise undocumented types from the diagrams.

Comment: True, but that's a problem in the case I describe where the code base is large and badly-written; many of the classes I want to see in the generated documentation won't be Doxygenated in source code, so using HIDE_UNDOC_RELATIONS would hide them as well as the built-in types.